# Magento Custom Options - make every first radio button checked

Tags: magento, radio-button

We have a Magento Shop with some products that have custom options as radio buttons. Every non required option has the first button checked by default but not the required ones. How can I make them checked?

I've allready installed the extension Dependent Custom Options (gallery). That gives me the option to set which custom option should be checked by default but that doesn't update the price to the right value.

Thanks for evey help

Answer (score 3):

This solution may not be the best for you, but I had this same problem, and just fixed it.

First I had to use a convoluted method for installing jQuery correctly in Magento. Part of the problem, I believe comes from the Spriptaculous Effects file being outdated with the latest Magento build. So I went to the site www.script.aculo.us and downloaded the latest version. I then pulled out the effects.js file and used it to overwrite the effects.js in:

> [Magento]/js/scriptaculous

Then I downloaded jQuery from the jQuery site and made a folder called jquery in:

> [Magento]/js/

And dumped the jquery file in there.

Then I opened the file:

> [Magento]/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/page.xml

And found a list of lines that look like this:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
```

I copied one of these and replaced the path to that of the jquery file like this.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js</script></action>
```

Now jQuery will be included in all your pages.

Important! You have to run jQuery in noConflict() mode. So this is what the JS looks like that (for me) worked to select the first radio button on any page with custom options.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

// auto selects the first input with radio class
$j('.options-list input.radio:first').attr('checked','checked');

});
```

I saved that file into my jquery folder and linked to it the same way I linked to the jQ library.

Flushed my cache, and voila!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery, as Gordon says, but to update the price you need to run opConfig.reloadPrice() function when check. So the code will be something like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

// auto selects the first input with radio class
$j('.options-list input.radio:first').attr('checked','checked');
opConfig.reloadPrice();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript function named something like `optionsConfig.reloadPrice()` which, when called, updates the price according to options. You probably need to have this triggered during the `dom:loaded` event.

Comment: I've tried it by putiing this: '  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
  opConfig.reloadPrice();
  });
  </script>
  ' in /template/catalog/product/view.phtml. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\select.php

You can find here your custom option title and set if condition with your title.

For example, my custom option title is price:

if($this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()=='Price'))